# Get Base64 String from form with file_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, base64

I have the following Form in Ruby:

```
<%= form_for @user, html: {role: "form"} do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :picture, "Picture" %>
    <%= f.file_field :picture, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <%= f.button "Save Changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

What I want is the Base64 String of the chosen picture in the form to save it in the database.

When I choose something and send it to the controller, it gives me something like this:

```
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000517a570>
```

I don't want to use plugins to save the picture on the server or something because it's just a little system.

Does anyone have an idea what to do in the controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, whether it's good or not, but i like the solution i found:

My form looks now like:

```
<%= form_for @user, html: {role: "form"} do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="filePicker">Choose a picture:</label><br>
        <input type="file" id="filePicker" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="invisible">
        <%= f.label :picture, "Picture" %>
        <%= f.text_field :picture, :class => "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <img id="img_preview" src="<%= current_user.picture %>" style="width:200px; height: auto; margin-bottom: 15px;"/>

    </br>

    <%= f.button "Save Changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I have an `input type="file"` where i choose the picture. That it's rendered in javascript as base64 String and show as preview. When a img already exists its shown before.

My javascript looks like:

```
<script>
var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var file = files[0];

    if (files && file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
            var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
            var fileending = file.type;
            if(fileending == "image/jpeg")
            {
                fileending = "image/jpg";
            }
            var test = btoa(binaryString);
            var final = "data:"+fileending+";base64,"+test;
            document.getElementById("img_preview").src = final
            document.getElementById("user_picture").value = final
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
};

if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    document.getElementById('filePicker').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
} else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}
</script>
```

Because i need something like `data:image/jpg;base64,BASE_64_STRING` i read the file type and add it to the String. I get some trouble with `jpeg` and `jpg`. Thats why i change them all to `jpg`.

Now i add the string i created to the invisible (css: `display:none`) text_field and send it to the controller, where i save it as simple string.

It's only my solution. There are better ways, but i like my one.

Only problem is the size of the picture. I will do an limit in my project.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but should get you going in the right direction

```
file_upload = params[:user][:picture].tempfile
user.picture_base64 = Base64.encode64(file_upload)
```

assumptions:

- your user model has an attribute `picture_base64` that is type text
- the file is being sent in the param as `[:user][:picture]`

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer.
How do you mean the last point?
I send the file with `user_params1[:picture]`, but i think thats not the file itself or?
I get something like `no implicit conversion of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String` or `no implicit conversion of Tempfile into String`

Comment: you might need to do an explicit open on the tempfile, i.e. `Base64.encode64(File.read(file_upload))`

Comment: Now i get `ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow`.
I think you can not send the file so easy how i write it above.
But i don't know :(

Comment: Hey, i found this Link in another stackoverflow-post: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/eliseosoto/JHQnk/) - i think i will read the base64 string with javascript, then write in an invisible form and sent it to the controller. With this way i can also show the selected picture before i send it. Not the best way but this should work without problems.

Comment: I just posted my solution. Not the best but i love it <3